# Ember-cli - Simple-Auth :: Location for factory authenticator:custom

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

Where is the proper location for factory in ember-cli. Once I have the proper location for the factory, do I register in my initializer as such

container.register('authenticator:custom', application.CustomAuthenticator);

```
// the custom authenticator that authenticates the session against the custom server
App.CustomAuthenticator = Ember.SimpleAuth.Authenticators.Base.extend({
    tokenEndpoint: '/v4/session',

    restore: function(data) {
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            if (!Ember.isEmpty(data.token)) {
                resolve(data);
            } else {
                reject();
            }
        });
    },

    authenticate: function(credentials) {
        var _this = this;
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            Ember.$.ajax({
                url:         _this.tokenEndpoint,
                type:        'POST',
                data:        JSON.stringify({ session: { identification: credentials.identification, password: credentials.password } }),
                contentType: 'application/json'
            }).then(function(response) {
                Ember.run(function() {
                resolve({ token: response.session.token });
            });
        }, 
            function(xhr, status, error) {
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                Ember.run(function() {
                    reject(response.error);
                });
            });
        });
    },

    invalidate: function() {
        var _this = this;
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
            Ember.$.ajax({ url: _this.tokenEndpoint, type: 'DELETE' }).always(function() {
                resolve();
            });
        });
    },
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's how you do it. Make sure though to call container.register before you fall Ember.SimpleAuth.setup.